# I am trying to write a code so each cell will open an embedded PDF

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a spreadsheet that we can email out to our customers.  I have wrote the below code so that when you double click the cell the PDF for that cell opens. I am stuck on writing the next code so that the next cell would open another PDF.  Any help is appreciated

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets("Attachments").OLEObjects("Object 1").Verb

Me.Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Cancel = True

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this code work? What do you need help with, specifically? What's the "next cell", and what's "another PDF"? Assuming "next cell" is `"$B$3"`, have you tried adding `ElseIf Target.Address = "$B$3" Then` just before `End If`, with the corresponding code in that new block?

Comment: I would assume you could match up the index number of a given cell in a set range with the index number of the matching OLE Objects